# Updating the child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationship table in between two tables which needs to be updated when i update one table. For example `TableA(id,name) Relation(TableA_id,TableB_id) TableB(id,name)`. How to update the table Relation while updating the `TableA`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set has_and_belongs_to_many in your models of TableA and TableB ?

Comment: @Rafal Thank you for your help; note that this should be a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: @Phrogz Sorry, I am still new and cannot comment on questions ... it will come :)

Comment: TableA and TableB has a one - one relationships between then so i kep has_one relation and throught relation in TableA and also TableB in relation i maintained belongs_to relationship to TableA and TableB

Comment: If its one-one then you should put the foreign key inside of TableB TableA_id. I dont see the point of having a relation table for a one-one relationship

Comment: ya i just dont want to bloat the model with too many columns and also future in consideration i want to maintain it speratelly for polymorphic uses

Comment: I think you will have to update the ids manually when creating TableA object and TableB object. Create another model that represents the relation and update it when saving

Comment: @Rafal My apologies, I keep forgetting that limitation. :)

Comment: @Phrogz You can give me the extra 20 points I need to have the ability for pointing it out ;)